# ADC interruptions in reading every ~1.5seconds

Tags: stm32

I'm using an STM32F476, and I have configured ADC1 to read from 9 different inputs.

My goal is achieve 200Hz, which should be very achievable considering the speed of the ADC on these MCUs.

The issue I am experiencing is that it seems the ADC readings are "interrupted" about every 1.5 seconds or so.

What I've done to configure this (code below) is configured the ADC to use DMA, and TIM3 at 200Hz. When the TIM3 interrupt occurs I call HAL_ADC_Start_DMA() and store this in memory for 5 seconds. Once the reading is completed, I write it to the serial port.

Code config for ADC, timer, looks like so:

```
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV128;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 9;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_2CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 11;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 33332;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
```

Interrupt on timer:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
      // start the ADC->DMA conversion
      get_adc_dma();
}
```

This function pulls the ADC (9 channels) and stores it into an array. When it's done, it send the data to the serial port (send_data())

```
void get_adc_dma(void){
    if (collect) {
        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)adc_buffer, ADC_CHANNELS); 
        memcpy(adc_pool[counter], adc_buffer, sizeof(adc_buffer));
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 1000) {
            collect = false;
            send_data();
        }
    }
 
}
```

My output isn't great: (one channel shown)
[image]

Suggestions on why this happening and solving it would be welcomed.

Comment: What kind of input signal are you sampling? The output looks as if your sampling a 100Hz square wave with a 200Hz sampling rate. This could explain the output.

Comment: `get_adc_dma` looks suspicious. The DMA is started and the destination buffer is immediately copied without waiting for the DMA to finish. That's unlikely to give the desired result.

Comment: @Codo Correct.  100Hz square wave sampled at 200Hz.    This should satisfy Nyquist.  Also, I've never seen a code example where HAL_ADC_Start_DMA() needed to 'wait'. They all immediately access the data, but I will explore this.

Comment: Your code likely doesn't have a problem. Instead, the test setup is the problem. If you sample a 100Hz square wave with a 200Hz sampling rate and the clocks are not synchronized, they will shift slowly. So after a certain time, you sample close to the time when the square wave transitions for high to low (or vice versa) and you get seemingly random data. After the clocks have shifted some more, it looks ok again. So use a more reasonable setup like a 30Hz sine wave instead of operating at or slightly beyond the limit of Nyquist. And the Nyquist does not apply to square waves.

Comment: Yea, I see what you're saying. That actually makes good sense.  I had better luck with 30Hz sin wave. Appreciate the tips!